# How do I write a .S file and make an executable out of it?

Tags: assembly, makefile

I have an assignment that involves writing a .S file and building an an executable out of it that returns 0. I looked it up and it said it was assembler source code, but when I wrote it like assembly it didn't compile. Can someone give me an example of a .S file or a tutorial on them that will point me in the right direction? In addition I have to make a makefile that will create the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt specify an instruction set so hopefully I have chosen one that is obscure enough to not do your homework for you.

You are going to want to know the calling convention or in this case the return convention.  Some compilers for some architectures use a register to return something some use the stack.

```
int zero ( void )
{
    return(0);
}
```

I will compile this with a gcc pdp11 cross compiler

```
pdp11-bsd2.11-gcc -O2 -c zero.c -o zero.o
pdp11-bsd2.11-objdump -D zero.o
```

and get

```
00000000 <_zero>:
   0:   1166            mov r5, -(sp)
   2:   1185            mov sp, r5
   4:   0a00            clr r0
   6:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
   8:   0087            rts pc
```

So it looks like for this architecture the return value is in r0. So we can shorten our already short program to be

```
.global _main
_main:
    clr r0
    rts pc
```

Unfortunately my pdp11 cross compiler is a cross compiler not necessarily made for building on top of the specified os.

```
pdp11-bsd2.11-as zero.s -o zero.o
pdp11-bsd2.11-gcc zero.o -o zero
/opt/gnupdp11/lib/gcc/pdp11-bsd2.11/4.7.3/../../../../pdp11-bsd2.11/bin/ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
/opt/gnupdp11/lib/gcc/pdp11-bsd2.11/4.7.3/../../../../pdp11-bsd2.11/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And that doesnt matter much because I dont have a pdp11 with an OS to run this on anyway.  But doing the same type of thing on a different platform that I can run on worked just fine.

Before you make a makefile you need to know the command line commands to execute to perform the task.  Perhaps make a script/batch file that executes the complete and correct commands in order to get you from beginning to end and then it can be as simple as adding one extra line of text and indenting and you have a Makefile.  Please dont ask that question here there is far too much info already here and on the net you should have no problems finding a very simple example to use as a reference.

Comment: PDP-11 - down the nostalgy lane... ;-)